# mybatis collection resultset maaping issue. Getting empty collection resultset

Tags: java, postgresql, jndi, mybatis, postgresql-9.1

I'm new to mybatis and facing an issue with getting a collection in a resultset. The resultset is defined as below:

```
<resultMap type="User" id="userMap">
        <id column="id" property="id" />
        <result property="userName" column="user_name" />
        <result property="enabled" column="enabled" />
        <result property="firstName" column="first_name" />
        <result property="lastName" column="last_name" />
        <result property="email" column="email" />
        <result property="password" column="user_password" />
        <result property="passwordSalt" column="user_password_salt" />
        <result property="lastLogin" column="last_login_time" />
        <result property="creationTime" column="creation_time" />
        <result property="lastEdit" column="last_edit_time" />
        <result property="validTill" column="valid_till" />

        <collection property="roles" javaType="ArrayList" ofType="Role" column="id">
            <id property="id" column="role_id" />
            <result property="name" column="role_name" />
            <result property="description" column="role_description" />
        </collection>

    </resultMap>
```

And the Java code looks like this

```
protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token)
    throws AuthenticationException
  {
    UsernamePasswordToken upToken = (UsernamePasswordToken)token;

    User user = null;
    user = new UserService().getWithRole(upToken.getUsername());
    if (user == null) {
      throw new UnknownAccountException("Login name [" + upToken.getUsername() + "] not found!");
    }
    if (!user.getEnabled().booleanValue()) {
      throw new DisabledAccountException("Login name [" + upToken.getUsername() + "] is disabled!");
    }
    if (user.getRoles().size() == 0) {
      throw new AuthenticationException("There is no role assigned for you");
    }
    if ((user.getValidTill() != null) && (user.getValidTill().getTime() < new Date().getTime())) {
      throw new ExpiredCredentialsException("Your account has expired!");
    }
    _logger.debug("Found user with username [" + upToken.getUsername() + "]");
    return new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(user, user.getPassword(), new SimpleByteSource(user.getPasswordSalt()), getName());
  }
```

Here, while logging in I'm getting stuck at the Exception saying `There is no role assigned to you`

About the code being right, it was working perfectly but I cannot make any change as I just have the WAR which I'm de-compiling using JD. The function `getWithRole()` fires the following query

```
<select id="getWithRole" resultMap="userMap" parameterType="User">
    SELECT * FROM view_boss_user_role
    <trim prefix="WHERE" prefixOverrides="AND | OR ">
        <if test="id != null">id = #{id}</if>
        <if test="userName != null">AND user_name = #{userName}</if>
        <if test="firstName != null">AND first_name = #{firstName}</if>
        <if test="lastName != null">AND last_name = #{lastName}</if>
        <if test="email != null">AND email = #{email}</if>
    </trim>
</select>
```

and the structure of the view is like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.view_boss_user_role(
    id,
    user_name,
    enabled,
    first_name,
    last_name,
    email,
    user_password,
    user_password_salt,
    last_login_time,
    creation_time,
    last_edit_time,
    valid_till,
    role_id,
    role_name,
    role_description)
AS
  SELECT boss_user.id,
         boss_user.user_name,
         boss_user.enabled,
         boss_user.first_name,
         boss_user.last_name,
         boss_user.email,
         boss_user.user_password,
         boss_user.user_password_salt,
         boss_user.last_login_time,
         boss_user.creation_time,
         boss_user.last_edit_time,
         boss_user.valid_till,
         boss_role.id AS role_id,
         boss_role.name AS role_name,
         boss_role.description AS role_description
  FROM boss_user,
       boss_role,
       boss_role_user_map
  WHERE boss_role_user_map.user_id = boss_user.id AND
        boss_role.id = boss_role_user_map.role_id;
```

A sample output looks like this

```
"id"    "user_name" "enabled"   "first_name"    "last_name" "email" "user_password" "user_password_salt"    "last_login_time"   "creation_time" "last_edit_time"    "valid_till"    "role_id"   "role_name" "role_description"
"1" "adminuser" "True"  "Admin" "User"  "adminuser@domain.com"  "SEli9hsMTTxGgjrlCz48+5w1CaMnUe/8xJJ0enOZ2ag="  "mBPa0wNPjvnGK3gzDMOHOg=="  "28-05-2017"    "28-05-2017"    "28-05-2017"    "31-05-2018"    "1" "ADMIN" "Administrator user"
```

I'm stuck with this error and I'm quite sure that it is the understanding of mybatis which is limiting me. Please enlighten me

Comment: What does the output looks like of the statement you decompiled in directly execution with your identity? It that correct? You can enable debug logging information of each sql statement and make sure the result of the execution of the sql statment is what you want.

Comment: Well there are few limitations here. I do not have the source code with me. I just have a WAR file which is guaranteed to be correct as it was in place in production for an year. But then the server was decommissioned and we lost all our database structure. My task is to revive the database using the decompiled WAR file. The collection of Roles within the resultset is being fetched empty which points me to that I don't understand the concept of a collection tag within a resultset.

Comment: It seems like you've solved the problem. Conratulations!

Comment: Lol. Sorry but no. My assumption says that the output of the query over the view should fill up the collection part of the resultset but when the java code checks for the roles, it find it empty!

Comment: Ok! Than my question is that do you have the correct data in database?If yes, then the query you've decompiled should also work in sql console. My suggestion is first make sure the data is ready and then check the sql statement. Anyway, it's not reasonable that it worked before but now fails without any changes. The most suspicious factor is the data has been broken ,or there is no data yet, or the data you've inserted or the view you've created is incorrect or the data in this view is actually not exist. The quickest method to verify that is executing your sql statement in sql console.

Comment: Yes. I think the problem is with the view query. The more precise question would be that "Can the query output shown at the end fill up the collection of the resultset or I'm doing something wrong?". If not, then what needs to be changed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145544/discussion-between-gemini-keith-and-shubham).